# How to include galaxy role in your galaxy role?

Tags: ansible, ansible-galaxy

I'd like to write some role and push it to the opensource. Before doing that, I'm interested in one thing - how to properly include third party galaxy roles ? I know, that I need to do specify this roles in `meta/main.yml`, I also read somewhere about `requirements.yml`, but to be honest, I didn't saw a complete example on how to do it. Could someone list a step-by-step instruction on how to do it ?

Comment: so you have the role already intalled from ansible galaxy ?

Comment: I need to include this role into galaxy role, which I want to export.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game but this seems to be what you're looking for:
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/galaxy.html#dependencies

So in your `meta/main.yml` you'd put something like:

```
dependencies:
  - src: geerlingguy.ansible
  - src: git+https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-composer.git
    version: 775396299f2da1f519f0d8885022ca2d6ee80ee8
    name: composer
```